# visualforce page to download "Salesforce Files"

Tags: visualforce, files

I've been asked to create a button on a Related List for Salesforce Files in Classic. So the Related List is on the detail page for a custom Contact page. I'm guessing I'll need to create a VF page but I'm not sure of the best way to tackle this one.

Specifically, clicking the button should:

1. Display a screen to user, allowing user to select which files to download
2. Open file browser on user's local machine, giving user option of where to download files

Any high level suggestions of the best way to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Files related list is not customizable - you cannot add a button to it.

[image]

You could add a custom button to the Contact page layout connected to a custom Visualforce page that would query for linked `ContentDocument` records and offer some type of download-related functionality.

It sounds like this might specifically have to do with downloading *multiple* files at a time - otherwise, you should make use of the native functionality provided by the Salesforce Classic Files related list, which already includes a Download link beside each file:

[image]

(Screenshot is of Notes and Attachments, but the Files related list has the same UI).

Comment: thanks David. We're not using Notes & Attachments so that isn't an option. I think I'm going to create a Contact button and try to do this with a VF page from there.

Anyone have an example of how to download Salesforce Files from a VF page?

Comment: I'm going to open a new Question to see if I can get help to figure out how to download Salesforce Files from a VF page.

Comment: I would suggest you take a few minutes to search first. Downloading Content Files is something that's been discussed on SFSE in the past. You may find what you need already there!

Comment: Also, apologies for causing confusion by screenshotting Notes and Attachments when I meant Files. The UI is the same, though.

Comment: Agreed. I wouldn't come here without searching first. I have had no luck finding what I'm looking for.