# Salesforce Files download from VF

Tags: visualforce, files

Anyone have an example of how to download **Salesforce Files** from a VF page?

From a custom Contact page detail, I want a button to open a VF page interface to allow a user to select **Salesforce Files** associated with the Contact to download to the local file system.

Comment: How is this different from your [question 2 hours ago](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/217498/visualforce-page-to-download-salesforce-files)?

Comment: Fair enough. I thought it would make sense to have more concise questions. The Files related list cannot be changed so the advice was to make it a detail page button. So now this question is specifically looking for a VF snippet on how to download Salesforce Files. Perhaps I made the previous question from 2 hours ago too broad.

Comment: Got it. I posted my comment before I read through and understood your previous question. The titles are very similar, so I short-circuited and jumped to a conclusion (mea culpa).

Comment: Yeah. No worries. I'll try to be more specific in the future.

Comment: How are your files related to the contact? Via a `ContentDocumentLink`?

Comment: Yes. We're using ContentDocumentLink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So Salesforce Files are really `ContentDocument`'s under the hood. You'll need a page to fetch the related files for your contact, and provide some information about them (name, file name, file type, etc) in a `apex:pageBlock` or the lightning equivalent.

On the related object `ContentDistribution`, which is created when you "publish" a `ContentVersion`, there are these fields: `DistributionPublicUrl`, `ContentDownloadUrl`. These objects & fields depend on some processes (I was making sure a `ContentDistribution` was available for each version & that each would always return the latest version), but these fields can be used to get download urls for a given file, through a lot of soql (three layers). This is probably only necessary if the other method I mention below doesn't work, but if your serving internal users, you should be fine.

You'll need to query your records, and that should look something like this:

```
SELECT Id, Title, OwnerId, FileType FROM ContentDocument WHERE ID IN (SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN :ContactIdList)
```

You can probably get away by using this download link instead using the ones provided by `ContentVersion` or `ContentDistribution`:

```
https://c.<instance>.content.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/<Id>?asPdf=false&operationContext=CHATTER
```

I took it right off the `ContentDocument` page. If you have a list of documents on a page, inside something with a loop (`apex:pageBlock` or `apex:repeat`), you could do something like this:

```
<apex:repeat var="doc" value="{!Documents}">
    <a href="https://c.<instance>.content.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/{!doc.Id}" download="{!doc.Title}">Download</a>
</apex:repeat>
```

If anything, you might need to provide some extra info about what file type is being downloaded, but this should work otherwise.